# "The workflow has been aborted" calling a InvokeMethod activity

Tags: iis-7.5, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

We have a secuential workflow that calls to a InvokeMethod activity. This activity uses a class written in C# and can take a long time to execute (around 50 seconds or more and calls to other wcf services). It is executed in a IIs+Appfabric environment.

Well, half of the times we get "The workflow has been aborted" with no more data in the exception.

Do you know if there is any "timeout" executing activities? Or a way to trace the error?

Thanks

Comment: *with no more data in the exception* BS until you show us.  Catch the exception, call `ToString()` on it, [edit] and add the result.

Comment: One place to look is in the Event Viewer control panel applet. App Fabric and IIS log to the Application Events log in there, which might provide some helpful hints in tracking down the underlying cause of the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

WCF services typically default to a 30 second window for a request to finish. You will need to update your web configuration to expand the receive timeout on your endpoint (both on the client and server sides) to 60 seconds or so.

A different approach (though much more involved) would be to design your workflow to support suspension and unload itself to a SQL Server database while awaiting a response back from your WCF services. This would yield significant performance & scalability benefits as well.